# How to add react-i18next to package.json if it seems react-i18next depends on i18next?

Tags: package.json, i18next, react-i18next

The [official docs of react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start) says:

```
npm install react-i18next i18next --save
```

which would add to `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "i18next": "^19.4.5",
    "react-i18next": "^11.6.0"
```

if `i18next` is the base and `react-i18next` depends on it, shouldn't we just list `react-i18next` and let it specify its dependency `i18next` requiring at least a certain version?

Comment: fyi: a newer react-i18next guide can be found here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb/stats

Answer (score 0):

You can check [package.json](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/package.json#L26-L28) of react-i18next, which it dosn't have an explicit dependency on `i18next`, therefore you need to install it by yourself.

I'm not sure for the reason for this, it does make sense to include `i18next` as a dependency.